# are daemon tmpfs executables copied unencrypted to memory upon execution? (prevent if so?)

Tags: security, memory, encryption, executable, tmpfs

When a daemon is executed, is the executable copied to memory?

If so, can it be copied encrypted?

If not, is there a way to prevent the executable from being copied to memory?

The executable is stored on an encrypted tmpfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a program is executed, the necessary code pages are loaded into memory on demand. This is transparent: the kernel loads the pages when it needs them, and tries to be smart by preloading pages that are likely to be needed soon.

The code has to be decrypted before it can be executed. If the code is stored on an encrypted filesystem, it is decrypted inside the filesystem driver stack, just like any other piece of data stored in a file.

It is pointless to encrypt a RAM filesystem. The key exists on the live system anyway (to decrypt the file). A subject can access the files if and only if he can access the key, so you need to do access control on the key. You might as well cut the middleman and control access to the files.

**[Access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control) on a live system relies on [permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions). Cryptography is not involved.** If you don't want certain users to access a particular file, change the file's permissions accordingly.

If someone has physical access to the machine, they have all the permissions they want. No amount of cryptography can change that. Cryptography protects access to offline data, which is stored separately from the key.

Comment: i was actually just about to ask about how linux stored its' keys for encrypted drives.  to be clear: it stores those in ram?  also, when you say that physical access grants all permissions: is that reading the ram directly or some other technique?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you want to bake a cake.  You don't know the recipe, but it's okay: you have your cookbook.  You take your cookbook out of your locked safe and open it... and here's what you see:

```
sN+zBL0+S/TNORDzFUADrzbv2K5A5zb62o1WPqDA/1vtfiOTVFJnVRaU/++JSjABIBWw7PjHm+cg
RnhGFHGv4xy0wTZi5vw8jTiJsgF6pzvOeVaDoiXdHliGFbiCM1rGxyziNesA5RLoLQx5EzGqNzw2
baF/4GCX7rW73E9BWeX+Spo8HCLBGni5MQ0MEYVQyGr4Xk6SJbziVagHZMDO6KLgj2a8QPANcYvT
fo4KYxkPIWe2gOukNsyLYLks5/JhTEs3b2aT4/MUuHe8xdXIBq+SbbX2QiTDhXYWK4gX2Ge63zU0
```

No list of ingredients, no directions, just gibberish.  I don't know about you, but I can't follow that recipe.

It's the same story with your CPU.  If the executable isn't in memory (the cookbook is locked away and not open on the counter), or if the executable in memory is encrypted (the cookbook contains gibberish), the CPU can't execute it.