# Execute in Place an encrypted ram drive

Tags: mount, memory, encryption, executable, tmpfs

I have found a few old posts claiming that `tmpfs` can execute in place.  Is this true?  If so, how?  If not, is there a ram drive alternative?

Can this be done with a ram drive that is encrypted?  If so, how?

Comment: Related question from OP: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77362 ... Sulla, it would be interesting to know the bigger picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is "execute in place" supposed to mean?

Comment: @HaukeLaging it allows a program to be executed from the drive rather than being copied to memory first and executed from there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execute_in_place

Comment: Having seen your recent questions on [security.se] and [unix.se], I can tell that **you do not understand what you are doing**. None of what you're trying to do makes any difference to the security of your system. I recommend that you stop trying for now, read a good book on security (such as [Security Engineering](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html)), and re-read the answers that I and others wrote. You are trying to defend against an intruder with a lock on the door, under the assumption that the intruder has the house keys — that just doesn't work.

Comment: @Gilles is this what i want?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need some very specialized hardware to do what you're trying to do.  Here are the constraints:

- The program must be in RAM, because that's where the CPU can find it.  It doesn't matter how it got there.
- The program must *not* be in RAM unencrypted.
- I don't know where you want to store the encryption key.  Let's assume it's stored in a TPM module, because I'm sure you don't want to store it in RAM.

Therefore, to execute your program, the CPU must ask the TPM module to decrypt every single instruction it reads.  This is not something you can do purely in software, unless maybe you have explicit control over your CPU's cache... which on most CPUs, you don't.  For all practical purposes, you're going to need an unencrypted copy in RAM, even if an encrypted copy is in RAM alongside it.

Comment: i'm confused.  if c++ can treat an encrypted drive the same as a regular as long as it has the proper rights, and i think i've seen that en/decryption is handled by the kernel then are you sure the program doesn't exist encrypted in ram?  the processor has to be, but do you have links talking about ram?

Comment: The kernel reads the encrypted data from the drive into one region of memory, then decrypts it into another.  C++ only sees the decrypted copy, which is why it doesn't care whether or not the drive itself is encrypted.  The program *does* exist encrypted in RAM, but the encrypted copy can't be used directly because it doesn't make any sense until it's decrypted.

Comment: ty!  would you mind putting that into your answer?